# how to change the background colour of a textbox on click

Tags: javascript, css

i am new to java script, so i had a doubt. i have created a form with username and password,i need to know how to change the background color of the text box on click? it will be helpful. 
My code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">    
 function AllowLock(){
               if (!locker.lock.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && locker.lock.value !="")
               {
                    locker.lock.value="";                     
                    alert("Please Enter only valid lock");
               }
               if(locker.lock.value.length > 5)
               alert("max length exceeded");               
             } 
function AllowKey(){
               if (!locker.keys.value.match(/[a-zA-Z]$/) && !locker.keys.value.match(/[0-9]+$/))
               {
                    locker.keys.value="";                   
                    alert("Please Enter only valid key");
               }
               if(locker.keys.value.length > 5)
               alert("max length exceeded");               
             }           

function LockName(){
 {
 if(locker.lock.value.length==0)
document.getElementById('errfn').innerHTML="this is invalid name";
} 

{
 if(locker.keys.value.length==0)
 document.getElementById('error').innerHTML="this is invalid key";
 }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("elementID").style.backgroundColor = 'your-color'`

Comment: This could be done with plain CSS like David Thomas and few others have mentioned already. JS is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the `background-color` while the input is focused (the caret is inside the `input` and the user is interacting with it there's no need for JavaScript, you can use CSS:

```
input:focus {
    background-color: #ffa;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/nYasr/).

With JavaScript, however:

```
var el = document.getElementById('inputElementID');
el.style.backgroundColor = '#ffa';
```

Answer (score 3):

add this to you button's onclick function.

```
document.getElementById('error').style.backgroundColor="#some hex value";
```

Comment: do i need to create a new function for onclick?

Comment: you can call any function. just add onclick"functionname();" in html tags

Answer (score 1):

Instead of on click, using focus would be better.

Use jquery for this.

Jquery looks different than javascript but it built with javascript. Just include jquery form the google CDN. Or download it and simply include it in your file.

```
$( "#divName" ).focus(function() { //give the div a name, and wrap the div around the text box
  $(this).css( "background", "red" );
});
```

EDIT: OH yeah! The guy is right! There is totally a pseudo class for that. ( A CSS trick that takes care of it)

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

Dont need JavaScript for that, Just add this style -

If you have some `id` assigned, Then using id `error` -

```
/* if your text box id is error */
#error:focus{
  background-color: #ff0000;/* red some color*/
}
```

else you always can use other css selectors too, for example by tagname

```
/* for input tags */
input:focus{
  background-color: #ff0000;/* red some color*/
}
```

Or by class

```
/* for `some-class` */
.some-class:focus{
  background-color: #ff0000;/* red some color*/
}
```

**JavaScript**

If you want to use JavaScript then -

```
/* assuming your input element has id - `error` */
var el = document.getElementById("error");

/* add a click listener to it */
el.onclick = function() {
   el.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
}
```

**Note**

Using css way is better than JavaScript because its clean, and `element-selector:focus` will automatically take care of setting the previous background color when you click outside the `input`.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any JavaScript if you just want to change background color in input boxes
just use the CSS :focus pseudo-class.

```
input:focus{
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

Check out this page to learn more about CSS pseudo-classes - http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-pseudo-classes.php

Answer (score 1):

I think is something like this:

```
 <script>
    window.onload="myFunction(
        var textbox = document.getElementById('elementID');
        textbox.onclick = changeColor;
        function changeColor() {
            textbox.style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
            return false;
        }
    )";
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery for this. It's much easier

```
$('#lock').click({
      var input = $('#input').val();
      var regex = '/[a-zA-Z]$/';  

      if(input != ''
      && !input.match(regex))
      {
          input.val('');                     
          alert("Please Enter only valid lock");                        
      }

      if(input.length > 5)
      {
           alert("max length exceeded");   
      }  

      //Here is the CSS part. You can change it of the button or the input field
      $('#input').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

And here is the accompanying sample HTML. Also, the maxlength attribute that can be applied to certain inputs may kind of make your "max length exceeded" function kind of unnecessary.

```
<input id="input" value="" type="text" maxlength="5" />
<button id="lock">Lock</button>
```